# how to split command line arguments equally in C

Tags: c, command-line-arguments

I am writing a C program using command line arguments.
    when ever i give a string in command line with space it splits to the sub files ,

for ex- sample output

```
$ ./cmdline 4646 313 256 96664

commandline args count=5
exe name=./cmdline
split_part1=4646
split_part2=313
split_part3=256
split_part4=96664
```

I want the same output without giving any space in between the string. How to do,each sub part should split with equal number of strings . please help.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main (int argc, char *argv[] )
{
  int i=0;
  printf("\n commandline args count=%d", argc);
  printf("\n exe name=%s", argv[0]);
  for (i=1; i< argc; i++)
  {
    printf("\n");
    printf("\n split_part%d=%s", i, argv[i]);
  }

  printf("\n");

  return 0;
  }
```

Comment: `each sub part should split with equal number of strings `...I did not get it all all. Please clarify.

Comment: Perhaps providing an example of what you intend to use/get might help us to understand you better.

Comment: "*... without giving any space in between the string*" you want the same output as per your question by putting in this: `./cmdline 464631325696664`??

Comment: @alk, in that case how can you know when an input ends, if you  have no rule or delimitator?

Comment: yes as given by alk ./cmdline 464631325696664... .... if each subfiles has 5 lines then output should be  split_part1=46463  split_part2=13256 split_part3= 96664.. I have used all methods i can but unable to get... one of my friend told to use system() to count the line and divide, but i don't know how to use. please help

Comment: @Yogarajan so every split has a fixed size?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! Also see [how to ask](//stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Comment: @ A B it can be of any size but should be of equal length

Comment: @user3121023 no it cannot be, because am not declaring the names of sub files manually.... and also cant give the condition =3,  because if i enter 100 characters and give the condition as 10 character per line, then 10 sub files will be created having 10 characters each

Comment: @ Sourav Ghosh ... thanks for your reply but i have tried earlier before posting the question here.

Comment: @ user3121023 i'll explain you clearly,using cmdline arg  i am going to enter some characters in a file( eg split), I am giving the condition of 10 character per line(this condition is mandate), If i am entering 100 char in the main file(during run time) then 10 subfile should be created having 10 characters each... The number of file created depends upon how many character i enter during run time, but the condition of how many characters a line must have should be defined in the program itself( if i give 50 char during runtime only 5 file should be created having 10 char each)...

Comment: I've got a feeling that you want to use `stdin` as input channel rather than the command line, e.g.: `echo '4646 313 256 96664' ./split 10` or `./split < file`.

Comment: I am trying to write a program that can split the file instead of using builtin split command, like a program for the split function itself

Answer (score 0):

Following the comments, a simple algorithm to achieve what you want looks like

(*for a fixed token size of `5`, can be modified as per requirement later*)

1. Check if `argc ==2`.
2. Calculate the string length of `argv[1]`, store it.
3. Take a variable to be used as index.
4. Write a loop with breaking condition as `index < string_length` and increment condition as `index +=5`.
5. use `printf()` (used for illustration, you can add storing part also) like

   ```
   printf("%5s\n" &(argv[i][index]));
   ```